# Why does this pattern not work in preg_match()?

Tags: regex, preg-match, delimiter

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?355lr

It works fine in that regexr. If I insert it into my preg_match() like this:

```
$reason = preg_match('/(?<=error\: )(.*?)(?=\; Request)/', $message);
```

it always returns a 0.

I assume its something to do with the way preg_match() expects the pattern to be formatted?

Comment: It's working nice for me.

Comment: Seems I had a stray newline that wasn't in the regexr example, but was being output from my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems okay for me. Check that $message isn't escaped or different in any way to that regexr.

```
$message = 'Request have return error: Invalid email syntax; Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"add_contact","params":["420a42ea1685c9a273f26378aa82081b",{"campaign":"nfzM","name":"Chris Allen","email":"eric","ip":"127.0.0.1","customs":[{"name":"phone","content":"123456"},{"name":"address","content":"123 Fake Street"},{"name":"city","content":"Chicago"},{"name":"state","content":"IL"},{"name":"zipcode","content":"0001"},{"name":"country","content":"United States"},{"name":"company_name","content":"Acme"},{"name":"store_url","content":"http:\/\/www.google.com"},{"name":"timestamp","content":"06.10.13"},{"name":"subscriber_ip","content":"127.0.0.1"}]}],"id":2};';

$reason = preg_match('/(?<=error\: )(.*?)(?=\; Request)/', $message);

var_dump($reason);
```

Gives back:

```
int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex instead, because you've used '?' to toggle the greediness:

```
$reason = preg_match('/(?<=error\: )(.*)(?=\; Request)/', $message);`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not in your regex itself, note too that `;` and `:` dont need to be escaped. However i suggest you to use this:

```
if (preg_match('~error: \K[^;]++(?=; Request)~', $message, $reason))
    print_r($reason);
```

Note where is *$reason*